# Internal pull up resistors in a micro-controller vs external pull ups

Tags: microcontroller, pic, pullup

Micrcontrollers such as PIC describe their pull up resistors as *weak pull up resistors*, what does weak signify?

When/why would I want to use external pull-up resistors on I/O pins that support internal pull up?

Comment: The linked question might not be an exact duplicate, but the first answer to that question provides a good answer to this question.